# How to extract lines start with "#" or "chr1"

Tags: regular-expression

I have a file looks like:

```
##Comment A
##Comment B
#Important header
chr1 content a
chr2 content b
chrX content x
```

I would like to extract line 3 and 4 to a new file, which start with either one # (not ##), or "chr1".

```
#Important header
chr1 content a
```

I tried to do

```
grep "^[^##]"
```

but that will exclude the line with only one # in it as well. I guess I can always do it in two steps, but I would appreciate better solutions! Thank you very much.

Comment: The negated character class `[^xy]` matches a single character which is not (newline or) `x` or `y`.  You cannot match multi-character strings with a character class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about OR-ing the two patterns?

```
$ grep '^#[^#]\|^chr1' file
#Important header
chr1 content a
```

Alternatively (the `-e` form is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html))

```
$ grep -e '^#[^#]' -e '^chr1' file
#Important header
chr1 content a
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please explain a little further for the first one? I understand "^chr1" is to select those start with "chr1", but how about the first half? Thanks a lot.

Comment: ... starts with a *single* `#` (i.e. `#` followed by any character except `#`)

Comment: The second example is actually valid POSIX `grep` semantics.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks - I always get confused about which features are GNU sepcific

Comment: @steeldriver Me too, but I have the POSIX manual on my system to check against.

Answer (score 1):

Always there is another solution. Using `awk` you can do it through following script:

```
awk '{if( ($0~/^#/ && $0!~/^##/) || $0~/^chr1/){print $0}}' file
```

Where the first part looks if the line start with `#` but not `##` and second part get the line if start with `chr1`, then print the result out.